# How to detect undeclared vs. declared but uninitialised variables

Tags: javascript

Here are two variables (technically, only `a` is a variable, `b` doesn't exist) in this JavaScript:

```
function func() {
    var a;// a is declared but uninitialised
    //var b; //b is commented out so b does not exist
}
```

How to tell `a` from `b`?

Both of them are `typeof === 'undefined'`.

If `a` is in the global scope, you can try `'a' in window`to tell it is **Declared but Uninitialised**. But what if it is in function scope?

How to tell if a JavaScript Variable is **Declared but Uninitialised** or **Does not exist at all**?

Comment: Why does it matter if it's declared or not if the value you're working with is `undefined` either way? I can understand needing to know if a property exists on an object but not whether it's floating around in a function body.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `try`/`catch` and see if it throws an exception. Non-existent variables will throw a `ReferenceError` except when using `typeof`.

#### Working Example:

```js
function func() {
    var a;
    //var b;
    try {
        a;
    }
    catch (ex) {
        console.log('a does not exist');
    }
    try {
        b;
    }
    catch (ex) {
        console.log('b does not exist');
    }
}
func();
```

Well-formed code should not really depend on something like this though.

Comment: don't you think try catch is a bit expense for this?

Comment: @chungtinhlakho I'm not aware of any other options. So long as it does not throw, I think it would be cheap. Good code should never need this though, so if you are concerned with performance, don't depend on this.

Comment: Sure, but why are you answering an question whose answer is irrelevant, at last until the OP gives us a reason for wanting to do this? It's not just that "good code" should never need this; it's that **no** code would ever need this.

Comment: @torazaburo The question was if it's possible, not if it's a good idea. :) Even if it's a terrible idea, it is still interesting that if there was some edge-case where you had to know, you could.

Comment: Sure, but there is no such edge case.

Comment: i once had routine that would brute-force lexical names via eval and rotating /accumulating letters. it worked, but i didn't find any surprises.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the last two posters in that there is a difference between b as undefined and b being a reference error. A try catch would likely be the only way. I ran several logical tests on your scenario and b always throws an error when it is not in scope. In the fiddle, all the lines but one will error.

To prove it, uncomment one line at a time and run the fiddle.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wq93zs1j/)

```
function () {
    var a;
    console.log(a);
    //if (a === b){ console.log('A and B are Undefined'); }//1)b is an error|2)
    //if((typeof a) !== (typeof b)){ console.log('A is not B'); }//b is an error
    //if(a && b){ console.log('Both a and b exist'); }//b is an error
    //if(a || b){ console.log("a OR b exists"); }//b is an error
    //if(a){ console.log('a exists'); }//A is not an error but does not write
    //if(b){ console.log('b exists'); }//b is an error
    //if(!a){ console.log('a exists but has no value'); }//a exists, but has no value, so writes
    //if(!b){ console.log('b exists but has no value'); }/*b is an error*/ 
}
```

Good question because I thought a check on a non existent var should just be undefined also. I tested in chrome 51.0.2704.79 m.

I believe the result is logically correct. b does not even exist to the point that there is no name b, so cannot be referenced.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can do `try ... catch` and if it throws exception then the variable is not initialized.

```
var a;

try {
    var value = a === b; // for example.
} catch(error) {
    console.log('b is not declared');
}
```

Or you can create an object and check if it has corresponding properties:

```
var object = {};
object.a = undefined; // declared, not initialized

var hasA = 'a' in object; // or object.hasOwnProperty('a');
if(hasA) console.log('a is declared');

var hasB = 'b' in object; // or object.hasOwnProperty('b');
if(hasB) {
    console.log('B is declared');
} else console.log('B is not declared.');
```

Comment: A property is not "declared". It's *present*, or *absent*.